# What happens with an instance if I create a new one with the same name in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, oop

I have a class called `assetTransfer`.
If I have a loop and I create a new instance with the same name, what happens with the "old" one?

```
For i = 1 to 10
   Dim assetTransfer as New assetTransfer
next
```

Do I lose the previous instance?

Comment: Not sure if you lose it, but why would you want to do this? Seeing that it will more than likely result in undocumented/undesired behaviour

Comment: I need to create a new instance for this class and add it to a collection. the snippet above is only the first line.

Comment: You don't need to declare a variable. You just add a new object to your collection.  E.g my_collection.add new AssetTransfer

Comment: Ok, removing the `Dim` then, what will happen with previous `assetTransfer` object

Comment: In the loop you provide each time you go through the loop the previous creation will be overwritten by the new AssetTransfer assignment.

Comment: Actually, in the instance above (and being quite specific) I don't think anything is being created.  The same object is being DIMmed but it is not being set to an instance of the Class so nothing is ever created or destroyed.  (Happy to be corrected).

Comment: You should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42656772/10223558

Dim ... as new .... should be avoided in most cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case specifically `assetTransfer` will never be instantiated, since it is never called. [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dim-statement)

The `dim foo as new bar` statement should be avoided in most cases, instead use separate declaration and instantiation like: `dim foo as bar` and `set foo = new bar`
Reason: [What's the difference between Dim As New vs Dim / Set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42656772/10223558)

A way to solve this would look like this.
At the end you have 10 instances of assetTransfer in your Collection

```
dim aCollection as Collection
set aCollection = new Collection
Dim assetTransferInstance as assetTransfer

For i = 1 to 10
   set assetTransferInstance = new assetTransfer
   'do something with assetTransfer
   aCollection.Add assetTransferInstance 
next i

debug.print aCollection.Count   '10
```

Comment: Thank you, is it the same of just `aCollection.Add New assetTransferInstance` and removing the line `set assetTransferInstance = new assetTransfer`?

Comment: No, `assetTransferInstance` is a reference (something like a pointer), not something you would instantiate. I guess you what you meant is `aCollection.Add New assetTransfer` which would work (afaik). If it is just to save some lines of code I would not use this method. Especially if you want to use the object within the loop.