# How do I pass an Object to VBA Class Get Property Method without receiving an 'Object not Defined' Error?

Tags: excel, vba

When passing a Worksheet to a Class Object Method, I receive:

> Error 91: Object Variable or With Block variable not set.

The problem is, I do not know where it is I have not set an object.

```
Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WS = oExport.ExportSheet(oExport.WB)

Dim testint As Integer
Dim oAsset As clsAsset
testint = oAsset.AssetIDCol(WS)
```

I have checked, and the worksheet object is correctly set in Line 2 of the code.  The error occurs when assigning a value to the 'testint' variable. Here is the `.AssetIDCol()` property from my clsAsset property:

```
Option Explicit

Private priv_asset_id_col As Integer

Public Static Property Get AssetIDCol(WS As Worksheet) As Integer

   If Not priv_asset_id_col = Null Then
        AssetIDCol = priv_asset_id_col
        Exit Property
   End If

   Dim rngX As Range
   Dim Val As Variant
   Dim i As Integer

   Set rngX = WS.UsedRange '.Rows(1) '.Find(SearchVal, LookAt:=xlWhole)

   For i = 1 To rngX.Columns.Count

   If InStr(priv_asset_id_col_name, rngX.Cells(1, i).Value) > 0 Then
       AssetIDCol = i
       priv_asset_id_col = i
       Exit Property
   End If

   Next i

   AssetIDCol = 0

End Property
```

How do I fix this error?  The `Get` property returns an integer, so I am not sure where I am failing to use `Set` in creating an instance.

Comment: `oAsset` is `Nothing`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error appears, because `oAsset` is declared, but not initialized.

The easiest way to fix it is to write `Dim oAsset As New clsAsset` instead of `Dim oAsset As clsAsset`. This way you are referring to a new object upon declaration.

Another way is to set the new object explicitly with a new line, after declaring it:

```
Dim oAsset As clsAsset
Set oAsset = New clsAsset
```

Comment: Take a look at [What's the difference between Dim As New vs Dim / Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42656468/whats-the-difference-between-dim-as-new-vs-dim-set) for some thoughts regarding those two options.