# VBA. Collection of class objects contaning a collection in turn

Tags: vba, class, collections

I need to create a collection with class objects. These class objects should in turn contain a collection.

So the data structure from top to bottom would be:

- Collection **"col_A"** contains class objects **"cls_A"**
- Class objects **"cls_A"** contain an integer "inta" and a collection **"col_B"**
- Collection **"col_B"** contains class objects **"cls_B"**
- Class objects **"cls_B"** contain an integer "intb" and a double "dbl"

Everything works fine until I try to add the "cls_A" object to the top-most collection. Then I get the following error:

```
Run-time error '91':
Object variable or With block variable not set
```

My code is the following:

Class Module **cls_A**

```
Public inta As Integer
Public col_B As Collection
```

Class Module **cls_B**

```
Public intb As Integer
Public dbl As Double
```

**Main Module**

```
Sub main()

Dim objB As cls_B
Dim col_B As New Collection

'Populate the col_B collection
'(with one element for simplicity)
Set objB = New cls_B
objB.intb = 5
objB.dbl = 5.15
col_B.Add objB

'Populate the col_A collection
Dim objA As cls_A
Dim col_A As Collection

Set objA = New cls_A
objA.inta = 2
Set objA.col_B = col_B
'Up to here there is no problem,
'objA is correctly created

col_A.Add objA  'Here I get the error

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`Dim col_A As Collection` doesn't create `col_A` -- it merely declares it. The line that throws the error is attempting to use this non-existent object.

Try

```
Dim col_A As New Collection
```

Alternatively, `Set` it after you declare it but before you use it.

Comment: That was it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I will suggest that you go for `Set var = New Collection` instead of `Dim var As New Collection`. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42656772/15597936) @DavidR