# Can I put a collection into a collection in vba?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, collections

I was looking for an answer on stack overflow but didn't find a good one.

Imagine that I have a first collection filled with 5 classes and those 5 classes contains a number (we will say 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 for the sake of example). Pretty basic data structure for now.
My question is, is it possible that can those 5 classes of the first collection also contains a collection which is containing 3 names ("aaa", "bbb", "ccc" for example).

With this data structure I would access to the names with this syntax:

```
Collection_number_1(1).Class_1.Collection_number_2(1).names
```

I was just asking myself if this was possible in VBA. Sorry if i wasn't clear this was my first question on SO.
Have a nice day !

I know that the equivalent is possible in C for example.

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Comment: If I'm not misreading, wouldn't Collection_number_1(1) already contain your first class, i.e. use Collection_number_1(1).Collection_number_2(1) to have the first name, depending on your entire structure of course. (I'm not familiar enough with classes to know how to access it directly)

Comment: @Notus_Panda I must add Class_1 field because the first element of Collection_number_1 does not contains only a class it also contains numbers. If i understood your answer

Comment: Was just trying to remind you that if you put a class in a collection, you get the first class with collection_number_1(1) (from what I've read on SO so far). I wish I had saved some answers to give you as an example more clearly.

Comment: Maybe read these: [first example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70143481/vba-collection-of-class-objects-contaning-a-collection-in-turn), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44701868/how-do-i-correctly-work-with-a-collection-of-vba-class-modules), hope that helps to explain more what I meant :)

Comment: Collections store items as the Variant data type. IN VBA the Variant data type can store any other data type. So Collections can store class instances as easily as they store longs. or strings etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the general gist of what you need.

In a normal module:

```
Sub test()
    Dim cls As Class1
    
    Dim namearr(0 To 8) As String
    namearr(0) = "bob"
    namearr(1) = "jane"
    namearr(2) = "alex"
    namearr(3) = "jim"
    namearr(4) = "fred"
    namearr(5) = "jill"
    namearr(6) = "sam"
    namearr(7) = "tim"
    namearr(8) = "cass"
    
    Set cls = New Class1
    cls.init
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(namearr)
        cls.add_data namearr(i)
    Next i
    
    Dim classcoll As Collection
    
    Set classcoll = New Collection
    
    classcoll.Add cls
    
    For i = 1 To classcoll(1).names.Count
        Debug.Print classcoll(1).names(i)
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

In a class module:

```
Private namescoll As Collection

Public Sub init() 'This could be a set to go with the get but I usually end up needing an init when doing similar things
    Set namescoll = New Collection
End Sub

Public Sub add_data(val)
    namescoll.Add val
End Sub

Public Property Get names() As Collection
    Set names = namescoll
End Property
```

I just named my class module `Class1`

You can add as many class instances and collection elements as you want.

Comment: This is not exactly what i'm looking for. Here you are putting a Class that conatins an array of strings into a Collection. i want to put Class that contains collection into a Collection. It's ok because it's pretty much the same. Ty for your answer.

Comment: I'm only using the array to populate the collection contained in the class, the class has no array.

Comment: My bad red bad perfect answer !