# Executing stored procedure with OUT parameters as well as returned recordset

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, stored-procedures

I have the following SQL Server stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CurrentlyPackingIncompleteBox]
    @StationID INT = NULL,
    @Product VARCHAR(30) = NULL,
    @PartsPacked INT OUT,
    @IAAOut VARCHAR(30) OUT
AS

BEGIN TRY
    
    DECLARE @PartSerial VARCHAR(30), @PartStatus VARCHAR(30);

    SET @PartSerial = (
        SELECT TOP 1 BP.LasermarkData
        FROM Box B 
        INNER JOIN Pallet P ON P.ID = B.PalletID
        INNER JOIN BoxPart BP ON BP.BoxID = B.ID
        WHERE P.StationID = @StationID 
        AND P.Product = @Product
        AND P.TimeCompleted IS NULL
        AND B.TimeCompleted IS NULL
    )

    --Get the IAA of the current box being packed
    IF @Product = 'DT19' EXEC GetDT19IAA @PartSerial, NULL, @IAAOut OUTPUT
    ELSE IF @Product = 'Hitch' EXEC GetHitchIAA @PartSerial, NULL, @IAAOut OUTPUT

    SELECT BP.LasermarkData
    FROM Box B 
    INNER JOIN Pallet P ON P.ID = B.PalletID
    INNER JOIN BoxPart BP ON BP.BoxID = B.ID
    WHERE P.StationID = @StationID 
    AND P.Product = @Product
    AND P.TimeCompleted IS NULL
    AND B.TimeCompleted IS NULL

    SET @PartsPacked = @@ROWCOUNT;
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    THROW 50001, 'CRITICAL ERROR.', 1;
END CATCH;
```

That I am calling from a Microsoft Access program:

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, cmd As ADODB.Command

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

cnn.Open DLookup("ConnectionString", "tblConnectionStrings", "Source = 'ClearToPack'")
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "CurrentlyPackingIncompleteBox"
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@StationID", adInteger, adParamInput, , 12)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Product", adVarChar, adParamInput, 30, "DT19")
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@PartsPacked", adInteger, adParamOutput)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@IAAOut", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 30)

rs.Open cmd
cmd.Execute

MsgBox cmd.Parameters("@PartsPacked").Value
MsgBox cmd.Parameters("@IAAOut").Value

rs.MoveFirst
Do While rs.EOF <> True
    MsgBox rs!LaserMarkData
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

As you can see, the procedure has 2 OUT parameters and also returns a recordset. It is working and the msgbox's are displaying the information. However, I am not sure it is the most effective way of executing the procedure. I am particularly concerned with:

```
rs.Open cmd
cmd.Execute
```

**Is this two separate executions of the stored procedure? If so, is there a better way to handle this so I am only executing the stored procedure once?**

Comment: You should not need `cmd.Execute`.

Comment: As Brian said above but keep in mind you are instantiating the recordset twice. You should avoid the `Dim [...] As New [...]` . See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42656468/whats-the-difference-between-dim-as-new-vs-dim-set

Comment: Unrelated note: using `Debug.Print` instead of `MsgBox` makes your debugging life so much easier.

Comment: Do NOT catch errors to only hide them by throwing a useless generic error.

Comment: @Kostas, point taken. I removed the New from the Dim statement and Set them in a separate statement.

Comment: @SMor, I do plan on doing something more useful with the error later, I haven't gotten that far yet.

Comment: @Brian, if I comment out `cmd.Execute` I don't get anything returned from `cmd.Parameters("@PartsPacked").Value` or `cmd.Parameters("@IAAOut").Value`.

Comment: @Linger Assuming the returned records are read-only, try a) `rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient` and b) `rs.Open cmd, , adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly`. The lock type is the default, just for clarity. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/open-method-ado-recordset?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: FYI, the output parameter values will not be available until all the query results are consumed.

Comment: @Kostos, using `rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient` and `rs.Open cmd, , adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly` worked. Now it calls the procedure once and I can get the recordset data as well as the OUT parameters. If you want to write an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those are two separate executions. Cannot test this for the moment, but both commands shouldn't make any difference, you can use either of them.

If you use the `cmd.Execute`, just assign the result to the recordset (in this case, there is no need to create the Recordset object in advance, just declare it as `rs As ADODB.Recordset` (without `New`)

```
Set rs = cmd.Execute
```

Comment: if I comment out `rs.Open` and `cmd.Execute` and add `Set rs = cmd.Execute` I don't get anything returned from `cmd.Parameters("@PartsPacked").Value` or `cmd.Parameters("@IAAOut").Value`

Comment: Sorry, cannot help any further as I don't have SQL Server available at the moment.  IMHO it should work as the parameter and the result are independent.