# Terminate method not called in Access 2021

Tags: vba, class, oop, ms-access

Anyone else finding that their Terminate() method in Access isn't being called?

Here's my code for my cBusyPointer class with the comments removed for brevity:

```
Option Compare Database     ' Use database order for string comparisons
Option Explicit             ' Declare EVERYTHING!
Option Base 1               ' Arrays start at 1

Public Sub show()
    DoCmd.hourGlass True
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    DoCmd.hourGlass False
End Sub
```

Typical usage is:

```
Sub doTehThings()
    Dim hourGlass As New cBusyPointer
    hourGlass.show()
    ' Do all teh things
End Sub
```

In previous versions, this class would restore the hourglass whenever the object went out of scope and was destroyed.

I even tried to manually destroy my hourglass object:

```
Sub doTehThings()
    Dim hourGlass As cBusyPointer
    Set hourGlass = New cBusyPointer
    hourGlass.show()
    ' Do all teh things
    Set hourGlass = Nothing
End Sub
```

The only way to fix this is to add a hide() method and call that.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Comment: You ask: *Has anyone else encountered this problem?* If I answer yes / no, would that be the answer you are looking for? If not, please edit and the ask the real  question for which you want an answer.

Comment: A yes/no will get me started thanks @Tom

Answer (score 1):

I cannot replicate the issue. The `Terminate()` method is called upon reaching the `Set hourGlass = Nothing`.

A couple of points:

```
Dim hourGlass As New cBusyPointer
```

This will create a new instance every time you call the `hourGlass` variable even to set it to Nothing. See the answer in the link below for additional info:

[What's the difference between Dim As New vs Dim / Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42656468/whats-the-difference-between-dim-as-new-vs-dim-set)

You should always use `Dim/Set` when working with objects.

```
hourGlass.show()
```

This does not even compile in VBA. Subs do not accept parentheses even when arguments are being expected, unless they are preceded with the `Call` keyword.

Lastly, the cleanest way to reference an object is to access it using the `With` statement which ensures the object is terminated when the `End With` statement is reached.

```
 With New cBusyPointer
     .show
 End With
```

Comment: This code has worked flawlessly since Access 2013 up to and including Access 2018 but with Access 2021 it fails, specifically build 14872.20158...

Comment: Also, I *want* the busy pointer to show until it falls out of scope so your With New example is not the desired result...