# Excel - VBA: Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba, web, web-scraping

I'm trying to automate some commands by getting some values from the web page, but this error appears and I don't know what it should be

```
Sub Test()
Dim IE As New InternetExplorerMedium

IE.Visible = False
IE.navigate "http://..."
Do
Loop Until Not (IE.Busy)


Cells(4, 2) = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("style363")(0).innerText

Stop
End Sub
```

Comment: you do not `Set` `IE` to any thing.

Comment: @ScottCraner but it's `Dim`med `As New` (which is still a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42656468/whats-the-difference-between-dim-as-new-vs-dim-set))

Comment: Possibly the document is not yet fully populated, or it is complete but there are no elements with that class name.

Comment: @TimWilliams it's not that, i tried to change it to "Tag Name" and didn't run too

Comment: Without a URL or the relevant source HTML it's difficult to suggest anything.

Comment: @TimWilliams it's because it's a private domain, the error is not related to the HTML address

Comment: You will get that error if `IE.document.getElementsByClassName("style363")(0)` is `Nothing`. Put a breakpoint on that line and then check if it evaluates to an object by typing `?IE.document.getElementsByClassName("style363")(0)` in Immediate window.